# How do I search for a substring with a quotation mark inside a string in Python?

Tags: python, string, escaping

I want to search for the substring "can't" inside a string in Python.
Here is the code:

```
astring = "I cant figure this out"
if "can\'t" in astring:
    print "found it"
else:
    print "did not find it"
```

The above should print "did not find it", however it prints "found it". How do I escape the single quotation character correctly?

Comment: May need to edit your question for formatting, if you run exactly what's there now you get "did not find it"

Comment: is your search string maybe `"can\'t"` instead of `"can\t"`?

Comment: If you are using `"` for creating string, then you can use `'` in your `astring`. So you can directly use `if "can't" in astring:`

Comment: I have corrected it, the substring should indeed be "can\'t"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to add \ before quotation.

```
astring = "I cant figure this out"

if "can\'t" in astring:
    print "found it"
else:
    print "did not find it"
```

or you can use "find" method, for example :

```
if astring.find("can\'t")>-1:
    print "found it"
else:
    print "did not find it"
```

Comment: wrong. `"can't" == "can\'t"` in Python. You don't need to escape a single quote inside a string literal that uses double quotes. The backslash is ignored in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
astring = "I can't figure this out"    
if 'can\'t' in astring:
        print('yes')
```

Comment: `"can't"` is more readable (you don't need the backslash if you use a different kind of quotes).

Answer (score 0):

One way is to define your string and regular expression as raw string. Then, look for a word pattern with "'t".

```
import re

string = r"can cant can't"
re_pattern = r"(\S+'t)"
re_obj = re.compile(re_pattern)
match = re_obj.findall(string)
if match:
    print(match)
else:
    print("no match found")
```

Output

```
["can't"]
```